# How to predict the mime type of a file based on its name?

Tags: python, mime-types, mime

This function is used to predict the mime type of a file
based on its name. If it fails to predict the mime type,
it defaults to `application/octet-stream`, aka arbitrary binary.
I would like to know if there is a more Pythonic / cleaner way
of writing this function.

```
from mimetypes import guess_type

def guess_mime(fname):
    try:
        return tuple(guess_type(fname)[0].split('/'))
    except AttributeError:
        return 'application', 'octet-stream'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Magic`](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) library:

```
import magic
mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
mime.from_file("testdata/test.pdf") # 'application/pdf'
```

Easy Install with:

```
pip install python-magic
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a `try/except` in this case, since this is not really "exceptional" behavior, but just the case that `guess_type` returns `None` as a type. A plain old `if/else` or ternary `... if ... else ...` would be more appropriate, making it clearer what the code is doing, and the latter is even shorter:

```
 def guess_mime(fname):
    _type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(fname)
    return tuple(_type.split("/")) if _type is not None else "application/octet-stream"
```

You could also use `or` to use `_type` or a default if `_type` is "falsey".

```
 def guess_mime(fname):
    _type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(fname)
    return tuple((_type or "application/octet-stream").split("/"))
```

Of course, in both cases, the conversion to `tuple` may not be needed if the function may also return a `list`.